# how to restrict the site from being indexed

Tags: .htaccess, search, indexing, robots.txt

I know this question was being asked many times but I want to be more specific.

I have a development domain and moved the site there to a subfolder. Let's say from:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/backup
```

So I want the subfolder to not be indexed by search engines at all. I've put robots.txt with the following contents in the subfolder (can I put it in a subfolder or it has to be at the root always, because I want the content at the root to be visible to search engines):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Maybe I need to replace it and put in the root the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /backup
```

The other thing is, I read somewhere that certain robots don't respect the robots.txt file so would just putting an .htaccess file in the /backup folder do the job?

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This would prevent that directory from being indexed:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /backup/
```

Additionally, your robots.txt file must be placed in the root of your domain, so in this case, the file would be placed where you can access it in your browser by going to http://example.com/robots.txt

As an aside, you may want to consider setting up a subdomain for your development site, something like http://dev.example.com.  Doing so would allow you to completely separate the dev stuff from the production environment and would also ensure that your environments more closely match.

For instance, any absolute paths to JavaScript files, CSS, images or other resources may not work the same from dev to production, and this may cause some issues down the road.

For more information on how to configure this file, see the [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) site.  Good luck!

As a last and final note [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) has a section where you can [see what is blocked by the robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449):

> To see which URLs Google has been blocked from crawling, visit the Blocked URLs page of the Health section of Webmaster Tools.

I strongly suggest you use this tool, as an incorrectly configured robots.txt file could have a significant impact on the performance of your website.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment and reminding about most things. One question though, do I need to to put a disallow: / to the dev subdomain so that files are not indexed? I want it only on the production... also what about duplicate content from that dev subdomain?

Comment: Hi Ilian, it depends on if the server is public or behind a firewall. Behind a firewall would be safer, of course, since you wouldn't need to worry about the robots file. There is some controversy on the duplicate content issue though, but to be safe, we avoid this as much as possible. One suggestion for if you're going to have a robots.txt on dev is to make it dynamically generated. If you have to keep  remembering to edit it before deploying the site, that manual process could come back to haunt you if the GoogleBot hits a disallow all entry.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply @jmort253 ! One last thing that I wanted to know ... I want to have sort of "secret" directory. Apparently if I put it in robots.txt anyone could open the robots.txt and guess it. There is a single file in that directory so I put a meta robots in it with noindex, nofollow but when I go to Google Webmaster Tools -> Blocked URL and try to fetch this page it says it is allowed for Googlebot. Why is that?

Comment: No folder on the Internet over port 80 is really secret. Security by obscurity really isn't secret at all. What you really need is some sort of security that requires a login and password... However, to answer your question, I think you could do the opposite: Use a `Disallow: *` and then add `Allow: /path` exceptions. The risks though are that you may forget an allow statement. My suggestion is to be sure to do plenty of research yourself before going down that road. I'd hate to hear of you doing something that has negative repercussions for your site ;)

Comment: No here's the reason why I want it done :) The admin are is located at http://www.example.com/admin, which is very easy to guess. There is secure login, ssl activated and user locked down for 30 minutes on 3 attempts, but I wanted to introduce one more sort of "gateway" so that you can't directly go to /admin and login. So I created this folder and put a simple file in it to set a session variable that allows you to go to /admin and don't get redirected. Do you get my idea?

Comment: Sure, a combination of the two, both cover *and* concealment :)  Take a look at Webmaster tools, if you haven't already. The section in there in "Help -> Blocked URLS" can help you ensure you don't block anything important.

Comment: Thank you for the involvement in this question, you deserved your answer to be accepted :)

Comment: @jmort253 Can we prevent indexing using .htaccess file?